# angularjs value comparison issue in jstl

Tags: angularjs, jsp, jstl

I'm passing values between controllers on different pages using angularjs.
This is a part of my app.js.

```
app.controller('JewelleryCtrl', function($scope, srvShareData) {
      $scope.sharedData = srvShareData.getData();
      sessionStorage.clear();
    });
```

and i'm able to get the passed values in the next page

```
{{sharedData}}
```

in my case this {{sharedData}} contains the value "Rings".
i want to compare this value in jstl but it is not working. this is what i'm trying,

```
<div ng-controller="JewelleryCtrl" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="fragment-2">


    <%    
        String subcat1 = "{{sharedData}}";
        request.setAttribute("subcat", subcat1);
    %>

    <!--<h4>Address</h4>-->
<div class="sell" onsubmit="return false">
     <c:set var="subcategory" value="${subcat}" scope="session"/>
    <c:out value="${subcategory}"></c:out>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${subcategory == 'Rings'}">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label>
            <select id="basemodel" name="sizeofring" tabindex="5">
                <option value="" selected="">Select Ring Size</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
             </select>
        </label></c:when> 
        </c:choose> 
    </div>
```

This comparison always fails.  Do i have convert the {{sharedData}} to string and compare? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's already a string though.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript (i.e. Angular) in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

So in the moment, when Angular takes over, there is no more `request` with its attributes, no more `session` (just a session ID cookie), etc. Thus, if you want to pass any value from your JSP to Angular, you need to render it. There are different approaches to that, the best one depends on your needs. You can do e.g.

```
<div id="subcat" data-subcat="<%= subcat1 %>" style="display: none"></div>
```

and then read the value of the `data-subcat` attribute, or set it as a global JS variable

```
<script>
var subcatGlobal = '<%= subcat1 %>';
</script>
```

and then use it directly. And few other options - if you google for `pass jsp variable angular`, you will get a lot of useful results (many of them pointing here on SO).